# postgres treat null as empty string when concatenated with string

Tags: enterprisedb

When I fire below query on one of our servers

```
     select null || 'query' ,'|',version
```

the result is null nothing is displayed

when i fire the same query on another server which has same version of postgresql server

I am getting result as

```
 query
```

postgres version on both servers are

1. EnterpriseDB 9.2.1.3 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52), 32-bit
2. EnterpriseDB 9.2.1.3 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52), 64-bit

Why this different behavior?

Comment: These are not both PostgreSQL. They are both EnterpriseDB. Do you also have any Oracle-compatibility enabled on one and not the other? I also think you've missed off two columns of results from your query.

Comment: yeah those are EnterpriseDBs and the version column  in the query is giving the version that is there at the end in my question . Problem is with  first column. can you please tell me  How can i check the oracle compatability?

Answer (score 2):

Check the setting of `edb_redwood_strings` parameter on both servers.

See more [Oracle Compatible Configuration Parameters](http://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.2/oracompat/Postgres_Plus_Advanced_Server_Oracle_Compatibility_Guide-04.htm)

> edb_redwood_strings – Equates NULL to an empty string for purposes of string concatenation operations. For Oracle compatible behavior, set edb_redwood_strings to TRUE.

```
SET edb_redwood_strings TO off; -- or on
```

Comment: yeah it was 'ON' on one server 'Off' on the other  Thanks, Peter..  I can't vote up. My reputation is too low